# Conditional route in Email notification failed in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send email notification based on condition to different route

```
$employeerespondents = AppraisalRespondent::select('id','respondent_id','respondent_email', 'fullname')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('email_sent',0)->where('is_active',1)->get();

                foreach ($employeerespondents as $employeerespondent)
                {        
                    $details = [
                        'sent_to' => $employeerespondent->respondent_id,
                        'sent_by' => $userId,
                        'user_id' => $userId,
                        'review_periond' => $reviewperiod,
                        'employee_respondent_email' => $employeerespondent->respondent_email,
                        'actionText' => 'View Multi-Source Feedback Form',
  'actionURL' => $employeerespondent->is_internal === 0 ? url('http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msfs/create', ['id'=>$employeerespondent->id]) : url('http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msf_externals/create', ['id'=>$employeerespondent->id]),
                        'notification_type' => 'MSF Request',
                        
                    ];
                      
                    Notification::route('mail', $details['employee_respondent_email'])
                                ->notify(new \App\Notifications\Appraisal\AppraisalRespondentSubmit($details));

                }
```

I am using if is_internal === 0 then to

```
url('http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msfs/create', ['id'=>$employeerespondent->id])
```

else

```
url('http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msf_externals/create', ['id'=>$employeerespondent->id])
```

But surprisingly when I submitted, I see this route on my brouser url with no parameter

> http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msf_externals/create

and I got this error:

> 404 Not Found. Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's `route()` and `action()` helper methods support URL params. The `url()` helper method, does not let you do that way.

So you may need to do either of these below.

```php
route('yourRoute.name', ['id'=>$employeerespondent->id]);
```

or

```php
action('YourController@method', ['id'=>$employeerespondent->id]);
```

And you used `is_internal === 0` this means it needed to be both the same value and type, you either change to `is_internal == 0` or do a `cast` in your model.

```php
    protected $casts = [
        'is_internal' => 'integer',
    ];
```

Comment: It now carries parries parameter. But everything is still going to appraisal_msf_externals what the value of is_internal === 0 :

> http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msf_externals/create/14

I now have this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error. An internal server error has occurred. If the error persists please contact the Administrator. Go Back

Comment: Everything now carries http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_msfs/create/{id}   It now has parameter e.g. 16,17 etc. But everything goes to the same url.. But no error message. None is going to external. Why

Comment: @mikefolu can you do `dd($employeerespondents->pluck(is_internal))` and show me the result?